# What should I do to get user know about scrollable content in the project/course

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, tables, responsive-design, readability

The project I am making has tables in it. I am working on responsive now. Big tables that do not fit in a small device, I have given them vertical scroll.

So my tables look like this in desktop
[image]

and in mobile it looks like this

[image]

The scrollbar appears when user touch on the table. I don't want to show scrollbar all the time.

I am thinking to give note below the table saying **"Scroll the above table to see more content."**.

> What else I can do so that users can easily get to know about
>   scrollable content and not miss the important content by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

My first question is, are you able to change/modify the table on desktop?

For me currently it is a bit unclear what the goal of the table is. It looks like a table where the user can see the balance of an account (incoming/outgoing flow of money) (forgive me if I am wrong).

### Yes I can change the table layout/structure

When I create an element in an application or a website, I always ask myself 'what question should be answered when the user looks or sees this element'. I will presume that this is indeed a table for the balance of incoming and outgoing cashflows.

As such I think it is best to highlight the difference between outgoing and incoming.

#### Example 1

This example has focus on all information in 1 table.
[image]

Here you can click the 'outgoing' and it will dropdown to show the results.

#### Example 2

Here you have 2 different tabs with the information
[image]

### No I can not change the layout/structure

If you can not change the layout, it will be harder to make it user friendly. You can, as you mentioned put some text under the table. Another option could be something like this.
[image]

You can put an icon in the darker area that hints you can scroll.

(I am sorry for the poor mockups, just started using Balsamiq as a mockup tool to test out)

Comment: I can not change table layout as it is an accounting format. liked your idea. upvoted :)